# Is it possible to import just one Key from an Object in REACT?

Tags: reactjs

I have an object which is humungous and has a structure like this:

```
const Values = {
    Name: ["First","Second","Third","Forth"],
    ...
};
export default Values;
```

I am interested in importing `Values.Name` in one `.JS` file. Does React support something like that:

`import {Values.Name} from "../FolderLocation/constants.js";`

If not is there any other way to import just one key from the entire object as my whole object is going to be too big.

Also, does anyone has any comments on the performance of the app in case I import the entire constant file in multiple components (about 50-60)?

Comment: You should be able to do something like `import {Name} from "../FolderLocation/constants.js";`, which will destructure the imported object to extract the `Name` property from it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the source file cannot be changed, and it uses the export syntax in your question, the only thing you'll be able to do is to import the whole object, then reference one of its properties:

```
import Values from "../FolderLocation/constants.js";
const name = Values.Name;
```

If you can change the structure of the source file, you can do something like this instead:

```
export const Name = ["First","Second","Third","Forth"];
// other named exports
```

```
import { Name } from "../FolderLocation/constants.js";
```

Using named exports will also permit tree-shaking *if* some of the properties of the object don't get used in a particular script.

> If not is there any other way to import just one key from the entire object as my whole object is going to be too big.

If the whole object will be used throughout the app, it won't matter - using `import` only creates another reference to the same variable in memory, and such references are extremely cheap.